# Typescript & React array of objects and returning JSX

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I just started a small project today to learn TS and its kind of driving me crazy.  I watched a couple of videos but none of them covered this scenario.

I'm fetching a list of movies after a search and am trying to render a list of them in this file.

the data should be an array of objects,
I saw a couple of examples that defined each key like title: string, rating: number, etc

I don't want to define each key as that will take forever... all I want it to check if it received an array of objects

my error is as follows

```
Property 'Title' does not exist on type '{}'.  TS2339
```

This is how data is defined and then passed into the component below

```
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState<Array<{}>>([])
```

MovieList.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

interface Props {
  data: Array<{}>;
}

const MovieList: React.FC<Props> = ({ data }) => {

  const renderMovies = () => {
    if (data.length !== 0) {
      return data.map((movie) => {
        return <Row>{movie.Title}</Row>;
      });
    }
  };

  return <Container>{renderMovies()}</Container>;
};

export default MovieList;
```

Everything works as expected if I remove the type definitions from MovieList.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a type declaration in your component's props. TypeScript doesn't know that the elements in the `data` object have a `Title` property.

You could fix this by doing something like:

```
type MovieListProps= {
  data: // your type here
}

const MovieList: React.FC<Props> = ({ data }: MovieListProps) => {
  ...
}
```

Also, the way you use `useState` might be wrong. It should probably be something like:

```
const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState<Array<YourTypeHere>>([])
```

Comment: i tried 
type MovieListProps= {
  data: object[{Title:string}];
}
got this error 
Type '{ Title: string; }' cannot be used as an index type.  TS2538

I also have another component where I did not have to use type declaration, and just used interface.  is type needed here because its an object?

Comment: I don't know exactly how your props are, but it should probably be something like `type MovieListProps= { data: {Title:string}[] }`